# Unable tuo build windows app with monaca

Tags: windows, cordova, monaca

I am unable to build the app in cordova 6.2.0 for windows with monaca.io.

It hangs after the  "Build for windows app" form "start build".
No error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some updates on the build server were going on these days. Try once more, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, now it works